# How to join two dataframes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I cannot get Sparks DataFrame join to work (no result gets produced). Here is my code:

```
val e = Seq((1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4))
var edges = e.map(p => Edge(p._1, p._2)).toDF()
var filtered = edges.filter("start = 1").distinct()
println("filtered")
filtered.show()
filtered.printSchema()
println("edges")
edges.show()
edges.printSchema()
var joined = filtered.join(edges, filtered("end") === edges("start"))//.select(filtered("start"), edges("end"))
println("joined")
joined.show()
```

It requires `case class Edge(start: Int, end: Int)` to be defined at top level. Here is the output it produces:

```
filtered
+-----+---+
|start|end|
+-----+---+
|    1|  2|
|    1|  3|
+-----+---+

root
 |-- start: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- end: integer (nullable = false)

edges
+-----+---+
|start|end|
+-----+---+
|    1|  2|
|    1|  3|
|    2|  4|
+-----+---+

root
 |-- start: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- end: integer (nullable = false)

joined
+-----+---+-----+---+
|start|end|start|end|
+-----+---+-----+---+
+-----+---+-----+---+
```

I don't understand why the output is empty. Why isn't the first row of `filtered` get combined with the last row of `edges`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val f2 = filtered.withColumnRenamed("start", "fStart").withColumnRenamed("end", "fEnd")
f2.join(edges, f2("fEnd") === edges("start")).show
```

I believe this is because `filtered("start").equals(edges("start"))`, that is as `filtered` is a filtered view on edges and they share the column definitions. The columns are the same so Spark does not understand which you are referencing.

As such you can do things like

```
edges.select(filtered("start")).show
```

Comment: Where can I read about this? I have another problem that when I do such a join with renaming in a loop then I get an `ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread driver-heartbeater
java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics._accumulatorUpdates of type scala.collection.immutable.Map in instance of org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics` exception from spark after 14 iterations?

Comment: @milk could you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074278/spark-sql-dataframe-join-with-renaming-in-a-loop